# The difference between ''which'' and ''in which'' in a specific situation

Tags: differences

What's the difference between the two sentences below? or is either incorrect?

A - > The way which you chose was good.

B - > The way in which you chose was good.

Comment: 'The way you chose was good' means 'You made a good choice of how to proceed'. // 'The way in which you chose was good' means 'You did well to choose in that situation [when you could have ducked the issue / allowed someone less sensible to choose]' **or** (but this is less likely)  'The manner of your putting your choice across was admirable'.

Comment: A - > *The way which you chose was good* describes the content, ie the choice you made. It doesn't need - in fact, it suffers from - *which*. It would be better phrased simply *The way you chose…* but since that's ambiguous, it would need to be clarified as *The way chosen…* 

B - > *The way in which you chose was good* refers solely to the process of choosing, not in any way to the choice.

Comment: To make it easier to grasp: “The way which you chose” = what you chose. “The way in which you chose” = how you chose. Neither is very natural-sounding as worded.

Answer (score 1):

Let me rephrase, this will make it clearer:

> A - > The way which you chose was good.  - > You chose **a way**.

This focuses on **what** you chose.

"Way" can be literal (choosing which road to take during a journey) or figurative (choosing how to proceed with a plan), but the key thing to remember here is that **you chose a way**.

> B - > The way in which you chose was good. - > You chose **in a way**.

This focuses on your **how** you made the choice.

"In a way" means "in a certain manner".

It doesn't tell you anything about what the choice was. You could've been choosing a meal, your favorite color, or what shoes to wear.
The key thing to remember here is that **you chose (something) in a certain way**.

---

### Examples

1. Consider the example of picking whether to wear blue or red socks today. You make a clever choice, and I remark:

> The way in which you chose was really clever!

2. Consider the example of having to pick which road you take to work. You make a choice, and we end up avoiding traffic jams.

> The way you chose had no traffic jams!

3. (Combining the two) Consider the example of having to pick which road you take to work, in order to avoid traffic jams. You make a clever choice, and I make two remarks:

> 1. The way you chose had no traffic jams!
> 2. The way in which you chose to take this route was really clever!

Can you see the difference between them now?

1. focuses on **what** you chose. *The route to work* was good.
2. focuses on **how** you made the choice. *Your method (of choosing the route to work)* was good.

Comment: This is very clear, especially for an ELLer.

Answer (score 0):

A: *Good* is an adjective describing the way, for example the method, approach, or route.

B: The process was good, i.e. the way you went about making your choice.